# In C# determining if an object o is an Action<...> or Func<....>

Tags: c#, reflection, metaprogramming

Say you have a Dictionary < string,object > . It might contain decimals, strings or other valid types. It could also contain Actions and Funcs like:

```
Action<string> or Action<int,int,string> etc.
```

Is there a general way to discover that a given key k points to an Action or Func and then invoke that same value?

```
var value = dict[key];
//some sort of predicate checking if value is invokeable
```

I have considered using the dynamic keyword and simply calling Invoke( args ) on the resulting object, but this seems slow and inelegant.

Comment: It seems to me like your storage mechanism needs to be rethought rather than a slow workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could test off it is a delegate:

```
Delegate d = value as Delegate;
if(d != null) d.DynamicInvoke(args);
```

However! Knowing what args to provide (in an object-array) is tricky if you don't know the signature ahead of the invoke.

Comment: Doh, it was capital D Delegate. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's hard to imagine that he would have the args available without knowing in advance the signature of his function, or even if he has a function to call.

Comment: I'm not sure this would be much faster than dynamic. To be clear, Delegate.DynamicInvoke falls back to reflection to invoke the delegate. I would expect it to be on the same level as dynamic with regard to efficiency. Dynamic might actually be faster with caching.

Comment: @Dustin, but dynamic doesn't do any static analysis for you.  For example, `d.Invoce(args)` would compile just fine.  You don't run into that problem with Marc's solution.

Comment: DynamicInvoke doesn't do any static analysis either. It's 100% late-bound and takes an object array as a parameter list.

Comment: A quick Console app test shows that 1,000,000 DynamicInvoke calls on a delegate takes about 4 to 6 times longer than 1,000,000 calls to the same delegate that is first cast to dynamic and invoked normally. DynamicInvoke does *all* of its reflection magic at runtime, but the compiler emits a call site to speed up the dynamic call.

Comment: @Dustin, the *actual invocation* of `DynamicInvoke` is statically bound.  `DynamicInvoke` *implements* a late-bound call, but it is not *itself* a latebound call.  And I'm not debating the performance part at all.  (Out of curiosity, what does the call for your dynamic version look like?  That would probably help flesh out the discussion)

Comment: I understand where you were coming from on statically bound -- i.e. statically bound to DynamicInvoke. The actually delegate call is definitely not though. The question mentioned performance, which is why I guess I'm belaboring this point. :-) It's all trade off. DynamicInvoke is going to perform better initially, but for several calls, the cached call site for dynamic will perform better. For raw speed its better to just check the type, cast and call. :-)

Comment: @Dustin yes, At the performance level, the *ideal* would be to know the function-type ahead of time and use strongly-typed .Invoke; neither dynamic nor DynamicInvoke feels particularly elegant here.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to invoke it dynamically via dynamic, or Delegate.DynamicInvoke, you could use some generic extension methods to perform the test for you.

First, make your dictionary a Dictionary<whatever, Delegate> rather than object.

Next, create a couple of extension methods (or more to match the delegate types you care about).

```
public static bool TryInvoke<T>(this Delegate del, T arg)
{
    var action = del as Action<T>;
    if (action != null)
    {
        action(arg);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static bool TryFunc<T, TResult>(this Delegate del, T arg, out TResult result)
{
    result = default(TResult);

    var func = del as Func<T, TResult>;
    if (func != null)
    {
        result = func(arg);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally, you use your extension methods like so...

```
var value = dict[key];

if (value.TryInvoke(20))
{
    // do something...
}
else
{
    int result;
    if (value.TryInvoke(20, out result))
    {
        // do something else...
    }
}
```

It's not hard to imagine building this up as a small library and re-using it.